# Azure Function Http Trigger validating body data

Tags: c#, validation, azure, http, azure-functions

Is there a way currently to validate objects in Azure functions using something similar to Data Annotations and Model State in the MVC framework? Or what is the standard approach to data validation and error response in Functions?

Comment: Here's an article that provides examples of validating Azure Functions HTTP triggers with the FluentValidation library: https://www.tomfaltesek.com/azure-functions-input-validation/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This mechanism doesn't exist today, so you need to handle this validation yourself, but this would be a great feature.

We have an issue tracking this here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1199, please feel free to comment and upvote!

Comment: I followed that github link and tried out Fluent Validation 
https://fluentvalidation.net/
It works quire nicely